# Dual boot Windows 8.1 + Ubuntu 14.04 - Cannot connect to my wi-fi on ubuntu

Tags: wireless, networking, dual-boot

just yesterday I installed a copy of Ubuntu 14.04 alongside my Windows 8.1.

I was at my relative's house yesterday, and the Wi-Fi there worked on both Windows and Ubuntu. Now I'm home and I cannot connect to my Wi-Fi on Ubuntu; however, I can connect to my Wi-Fi on windows.

I have googled and searched for about an hour now, and the only posts I can find with my same problem do not have answers yet and are a dated at least a year ago.

One other thing: I'm currently on my Ubuntu installation to make this post, but I am wired with ethernet into my router.

So my main problem is I can't connect to my home network on wifi in Ubuntu, but I can in Windows without a problem

Anything helps! If I need to give more information, just let me know

Comment: Could you run [this wireless script](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/57264241/wireless_script) to see what's going on and post the output to http://paste.ubuntu.com and provide the link back here?

Comment: Hello again! I made this post a bit back and completely forgot about it because I don't have this problem anymore. Somehow my laptop was just randomly able to connect the next day and I was quite confused because I knew there had to be some sort of reason. I could still run that script if you'd like? But I'm not sure if it would make a difference since I'm able to connect now

Comment: **Hint:** Answer your own question by incorporating the comment above and then "accept" your own question. (Your reputation will go up)!
And then, schmucks like me who trawl the site for unsolved (thus interesting questions) will not bother you any more!  ;-)

Comment: Aha, you're not bothering whatsoever, thank you very much as I'm still fairly new to this website!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted this a while back around when I'd first installed Ubuntu on my laptop, and now seem to have no problems with my Wi-Fi connection to my home network. I just woke up one day and I was able to connect. Basically I never had a definite problem I could find, and hopefully it continues to work.

(It was probably solved by an update, so turn on your updates!)